# WAMP Server Apache won't start

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, apache2.4

There are several topics that are very similar to this one, however, after looking over them the ones that were solved I did not have the same issue, and the rest weren't solved.

I have installed a new version of WAMP.  No changes made to any files.

Opening wamp the icon never goes from red to green.

Put online gives error:
Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The service has not been started

That's the same error I get if I do apache->service->start service

I have not ever had skype running, but I uninstalled it just in case and because I no longer use it.

Doing apache->service->test port 80 says "Your port 80 is not actually used."  Install service gives no complaints either.

I've clicked the apache version apache->version->number

I have apache 2.4.9
Running windows 7
Wamp version 2.5(fresh installer like 2 hours ago...)

In cmd running "httpd.exe -e debug" in directory apache\apache2.4.9\bin prints the folowing:

```
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module access_compat_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_access_compat.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module actions_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_actions.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module alias_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_alias.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module allowmethods_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_allowmethods.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module asis_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_asis.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module auth_basic_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_core_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authn_core.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_file_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authn_file.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_core_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authz_core.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_groupfile_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_host_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authz_host.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_user_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_authz_user.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module autoindex_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_autoindex.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.548528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module cache_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_cache.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module cache_disk_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_cache_disk.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module cgi_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_cgi.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module deflate_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_deflate.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module dir_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_dir.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module env_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_env.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module file_cache_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_file_cache.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module include_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_include.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module isapi_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_isapi.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module log_config_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_log_config.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module mime_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_mime.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module negotiation_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_negotiation.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module setenvif_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_setenvif.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.704528 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module vhost_alias_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
[Sat Jan 31 23:05:21.720128 2015] [so:debug] [pid 532:tid 132] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module php5_module from C:/Users/Chase/Google Drive/Web Dev/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll
```

Running httpd.exe no longer gives me any issues.

But regardless WAMP will not go online.

**Addition:**
Could this maybe be caused by windows UAC?  I'm an admin and I even run wamp as an admin.  But I'm unsure what "Access Denied" means, and I don't seem to get any issues running httpd.exe by hand. (Although I don't know if it was functioning I was not getting errors)

**Addition 2**
I found a miscillaneous comment about wamp services on another stackoverflow question.  In Windows+R -> services.msc right clicking wampapache64 and selecting start returns "Error 5: Access is denied"

**Addition 3**
It seems this computer may have some other issues.  Attempting to change the firewall returns an error as well.  Maybe I have some sort of deeper issue.

**Additional** firewall issue details:
Clicking windows firewall in control panel says "Update your Firewall settings - Windows firewall is not using the recommended settings to protect your computer." then there is a "Use Recommended Settings" button, and clicking it says "Windows Firewall can't change some of your settings.  Error code 0x80070424"

Comment: If you have installed skype or teamviewer then first please stop and exit these and then try to start Wamp. (its due to Port allocation)

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I've uninstalled skype and teamviewer and as I mentioned I checked the port allocation using the apache tool to check the port.

Comment: Maybe some firewall or windows UAC issue.

Comment: One more thing you can try, is to uninstall WAMP and re-install it to some other port, say 81 or 8080 or whatever. I remember reading on stack overflow that someone had a similar issue with XAMPP and they did this.

Comment: I myself had to do this while installing XAMPP, though not with WAMP.

Comment: @WhirlMind I don't recall WAMP having a setting for the port in the installer.  And I don't know that that should matter if apache says port 80 is available via the tool.

Comment: What kind of error do you get with the firewall?

Comment: @Shomz see added information in post

Comment: Ouch, hope it's not a rootkit: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/error-code-0x80070424-with-windows-firewall/ec3fc3b8-69ec-4b4b-a703-4b745fe6e8ee

Comment: @Shomz I don't have a System64 or the file in System32, I have SysWOW64 but it doesn't sound like that was bad.  So I shouldn't have that issue?

Comment: I'm still investigating potential solutions proposed on links from the post linked to by Shomz

Comment: Not sure, I'd still scan the whole thing using a decent anti-virus.

Comment: @Shomz yeah got malwarebytes doing a scan.  I'm suprised I didn't have it on this computer, but I had AVG.  Hopefully malwarebytes'll find my problem.

Comment: Take a look at the Windows Event Viewer, look for errors from APACHE and MYSQL. What does that tell you? Also check youhave all the required MSVC runtimes installed [see this Post on the WAMPServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I checked into those things.  I have all the redistributables, and I couldn't find any apache or mysql errors in the event log(Though I may not be proficient at looking...)

Comment: Just a point. You dont need to `Put Online` all that does is change the Apache security to allow access from any ip address rather than the default which is to allow access only from the PC running WAMPServer. However, the WAMPServer icon should go GREEN.

Comment: Are you running 32bit or 64bit Windows? Either way it might be a good idea to try uninstalling WAMPServer, then deleting the `\wamp\` folder completely. Then install the 32bit WAMPServer, it runs just fine on a 64bit Windows. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: 64bit, I suppose i'll try installing 32bit

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this on last week!!i hope it's help you. If you are on Windows, You go to

```
"Control Panel" >> "System And Security" >>  "Administrative Tools" >> "Component Services" >> "Services (LOCAL)"
```

Now, since you are using WAMP and not IIS you should disable the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and the "Web Deployment Agent Service". You are good to go.

If this doesn't work you probably have Skype using Port 80 (if you actually have Skype). (If you have IIS installed you should also disable it. But if you don't have it installed you shouldn't worry!)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot even run wampapache from services that is: because some other software on your system is using port 80 for its communication so best thing is to shut it down so try turning down:
**Skype**
**IIS**
or **usb router services**